# Large if, but need to match a name base on criteria

Tags: excel

I have a table like this (Sheet2):
[image]

Where im gonna be adding next columns in the future.
The thing i want to do is, create a small table with TOP 10 users (Sheet1), base on the criteria which is date in cell B2.
Like that:
[image]

I've manage to retrieve TOP 10 scores based on criteria (cell B2)

```
=LARGE(IF(branch_units!$C$2:$O$2=$B$2,branch_units!$C$3:$D$48),D3)
```

But i really can't match names with the score.
Is it possible? Can someone try to explain it to me with an example? Thank You all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX/MATCH` like below

```
=INDEX(Branch_units!$B$3:$B$8,MATCH(F3,Branch_units!$C$3:$C$8,0))
```

If you want to select columns dynamically based on date then use below formula.

```
=INDEX(Branch_units!$B$3:$B$8,MATCH(F3,INDEX(Branch_units!$C$3:$G$8,,MATCH($B$2,Branch_units!$C$2:$G$2,0)),0))
```

So, when you change date on `B2` cell, your score column will change and still you will get name for that changes.

[image]